# Recovering saved password in Filezilla

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, filezilla, recover

Unfortunately I can not remember the password of FTP server, but it is saved in FileZilla Site Manager (Ubuntu).

How can I *view* the saved password?

Comment: very offtopic. --> superuser.com

Comment: `find . -iname "filezilla"` gives `/home/[username]/.config/filezilla` in my case. Then take the `sitemanager.xml` and look for the `Pass` element. It might be base64 encoded; [base64 decoders](https://www.base64decode.org/) are available en masse.

Comment: all incorrect answers; if you use master pass all that steps not work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Export your Site Manager information and you'll find them in plain text:

```
File > Export > Export Site Manager entries
```

It exports everything in XML like this:

```
<Server>
 <Host>ftp.example.com</Host>
 <Port>21</Port>
 <Protocol>0</Protocol>
 <Type>0</Type>
 <User>root</User>
 <Pass>mypass</Pass>
 [etc]
</Server>
```

Comment: This file had no entries for me, but werner's answer below worked.

Comment: But in my case password is saved under base64 encoding. Respective "pass" entry is as like as below :-
<Pass encoding="base64">some text</Pass>

What should I do now ?

Comment: You can decode it using a tool like this: https://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html but be aware that it's safer to write your own script for knowing 100% that nobody stores the decoded result.

Answer (score 11):

All passwords are stored in plain text in this file:

```
/home/username/.filezilla/recentservers.xml
```

And for newer versions of filezilla and ubuntu, `/home/username/.config/filezilla/recentservers.xml`
If the passwords are base64 encoded, https://www.base64decode.org/ can be used to get the original password.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu Linux FileZilla SiteManager file:

> /home/username/.filezilla/sitemanager.xml

Comment: Ubuntu Linux FileZilla SiteManager file:

    /home/username/.filezilla/sitemanager.xml

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't store your passwords in the Site Manager, but only used 'Quick connect', you can still retrieve them from the history: they are stored in filezilla.xml in the following directory :

Windows XP/2K: “C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\FileZilla”

Windows Vista: “C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\”

Linux: “/home/username/.filezilla/”